# Animate dotted polyline between two points on map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps, google-polyline

I am trying to create a dynamic number of points between two points on map. While this is quite easy and can be done by using the dotted lines from `PolylineOptions`, i also want to animate these points. I don't think there is any way provided by `PolylineOptions` to animate the dots of that polyline (like in Uber app).

Is there a way to put animated vector drawables on the map? Or do i need to use an `MapOverlayLayout` on the map surface and draw on it? Or any other way to achieve this effect?

Comment: have you solved it @Divya